# SASS Mixin not working

Tags: sass, mixins

one of my mixins seems to not work correctly when working with hr (horizonal rule) - I think it's just reverting to the default styling. I've passed in two variables which are simply the colors of the radial gradient. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong because I can't quite see it. I have added the correct includes and imports in the file.

```
<hr class="fancy-line">
__________________________________________________________

@mixin horizontal-line-styles ($color1, $color2) {
    hr { 
        border: 0; 
        height: 1px;
    &:after {
        content:'';
        height: 0.5em;
        top: 1px;
    }
    &:before, hr:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }
    hr, hr:before {
        background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, $color1 0%, $color2 75%);
    }
  }
} 
__________________________________________________________
.fancy-line {
    @include horizontal-line-styles(#e0afaf, #e0afaf); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

```
@mixin horizontal-line-styles ($color1, $color2) {
  height: 1px;
  border: none;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, $color1 0%, $color2 75%);
} 

.fancy-line {
    @include horizontal-line-styles(blue, red); 
}
```

Or if you really want to use pseudo elements:

```
@mixin horizontal-line-styles-1 ($color1, $color2) {
  position: relative;
  border: none;

  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, $color1 0%, $color2 75%);
  }
} 

.fancy-line-1 {
    @include horizontal-line-styles-1(blue, red); 
}
```

Codepen **[Demo](http://codepen.io/3rdthemagical/pen/NpJKeW)**.

---

What's wrong with original code?

At first it is bad formatted. Fixed:

```
@mixin horizontal-line-styles ($color1, $color2) {
  hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;

    &:after {
      content: '';
      height: 0.5em;
      top: 1px;
    }

    &:before,
    hr:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
    }

    hr,
    hr:before {
      background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, $color1 0%, $color2 75%);
    }    
  }
}
```

When you call your mixin:

```
.fancy-line {
    @include horizontal-line-styles(#e0afaf, #e0afaf); 
}
```

following css code is generated:

```
.fancy-line hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
}
.fancy-line hr:after {
  content: '';
  height: 0.5em;
  top: 1px;
}
.fancy-line hr:before, 
.fancy-line hr hr:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.fancy-line hr hr,
.fancy-line hr hr:before {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #ff0000 0%, #008000 75%);
}
```

First line: `.fancy-line hr` means that element `hr` must be inside element with `fancy-line` class name. But you have `hr` **with** this class name: `<hr class="fancy-line">`. So none of these css rules are applied.

Css `background` is applied to `.fancy-line hr hr:before`. You don't have this element. That why your code doesn't work. Alse you can look at some strange rules that are generated: `.fancy-line hr hr:after`, `.fancy-line hr hr:before`, `.fancy-line hr hr`.

My idea is to set `background` directly to `.fancy-line` element (code example #1) and don't use `:before` and `:after` elements.

Comment: Can i ask was anything wrong with the question I asked?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've still had to resort to repeated code using the mixin doesn't achieve the desired look for my hr.